# Can a rails model (or variable) be held in server memory and available to all sessions / jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby-on-rails application running on a Raspberry Pi, with database on flash storage. The application provides a means of logging and viewing the state of various hardware devices (GPIO & USB) via a web-client on the user's phone.

The application has a background job that reads the current position from an external GPS every few seconds. All processes (web client views and other background jobs) need access to this position information whenever they run.  The obvious method would be to create a simple model, e.g. CurrentPosition with the lat and long fields, and have the background job update the model each time it gets a new GPS fix.

However, given that the database is running on flash, and given that the position gets updated every few seconds, I am concerned about writing to the same location in the database repeatedly, continuously.

The location info does not need to be perpetuated if the power goes off.  So the obvious improvement is to store this info in server memory.

Questions:

1. Am I right to be concerned about the excessive flash write cycles if I use the database?
2. Can I create a model housed in memory, rather than database (but keep other models in the db)?
3. Or is some form of global variable a better solution?  And if so, can these be accessed by other client sessions and other background jobs which will presumably have their own ruby instance?

or any other innovative (or obvious) solutions.

Matt

Comment: I am assuming your job is a rails active job. Or at least had access to your rails env.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t have to be a full blown model, just a plain ruby object. That way you’re clearly separating it from your perdiste models

You could store this in memory by

```
config/initializers/position.rb

class LatLon

    NOW = [0.0, 0.0]

  end
```

And then access that constant anywhere in the rails environment using `LatLon::NOW`  Use your job to update the value and read the value elsewhere.

You can use the class to store other things -

- a better null value if the job hasn’t run yet
- history which you can dump out at shutdown if you want persistence but just less frequent writes
- a time stamp so you can check the age of the position before committing a GPIO data log against it
- format it with getters and setters in stead of a clunky CONSTANT like I’ve used

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried your class+constant approach out. But though both the background job (running in queue_classic or resque) and a rails console can access the class & constant, they appear to be accessing different instances of it. i.e. changes either make cannot be seen by the other process.  This is what I expected given that background processes each run their own instance of ruby - I assume each loads their own instance of the environment to go with it.  Or am I misunderstanding what I see?

Comment: Yes. Of course. With different instances of ruby youre forced to have different instances of the class. Does your main rails app create the job and you can pass the instance to the job?

Comment: Alternatively - what is the backend you’re using for the job queue? If it’s redis you can use that as an in memory store which all ruby instances can access. If it’s SQL, then that’s probably a much bigger drain on the flash memory writes than anything the latlon storage would cause - so you should use redis, and then take advantage of having that to store the latlon as k/v